# MVC question: direct modell <-> view communication - why?

Tags: model-view-controller

can anybody tell me, why communicates the model direct with the view in the MVC pattern, and why not just throught the controller?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: Where exactly does the model communicate with the view in this WP article?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes it is **too costly** to use `Controller` for simple `View/Model` communication.

[image]

If your view just shows raw data without any operation (filtration, visualization, modification ...) it is easy to forget about Controller.

But this behavior is so **abuse-able** sometimes it kills all of the advantages of **MVC**.

And this where **MVP** comes in:

MVP (Model-View-Presenter) cuts the connection between model and view and every thing pass through man-in-the-middle (Presenter).

[image]

Comment: That's why I'm asking that, it was my opinion too

Answer (score 0):

The views know of the model and will interact with the model.

- If a button is clicked an action message might be sent to a model object in order to get
  something done.
- If a new value is typed into an entry field an update message might be sent to a model
  object in order to give it its new value.
- If a value is needed for a display an enquiry message might be sent to a model object in
  order to get a value.